# Lambda expression arguments

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library, moq, func

I'm trying to create an extension method for Moq where I can send in an expression to be used in an async return function. However this question is not really Moq specific. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult, T>(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> setup, Func<T, TResult> valueFunc) where TMock : class
{
    return setup.Returns(Task.FromResult(valueFunc.Invoke(default(T))));
}
```

This is how I'm hoping to use it.

```
repo.Setup(x => x.FindAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>())).ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<T, bool>> e) => context.GetSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(e));
```

Now I don't really know how all of this works and the thing I can't figure out is how to I get the expression passed on into the ReturnsAsync function so I can use it as the argument instead of the default(T) that I put there as a placeholder.

As expected the "e" variable here becomes null.

Comment: How would you code it, were it not `async`? That'd be a good starting point.

Comment: The async part is not really relevant either, the thing is just that in Moq there is a function just like this called Returns (but not for async) which does what I want but I can't figure out how exactly. What I would probably do myself is send the expression as it's own parameter but I want to figure out how to make this work since it looks better.

Comment: In where you're hoping to use it, that `Returns` call should be `ReturnsAsync`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, in the second code block it's supposed to be ReturnsAsync indeed. Will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will do what you want:

```
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult, T>(
        this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> setup, 
        Func<Expression<Func<TResult, T>>, TResult> valueFunc)
    where TMock : class
{
    return setup.Returns<Expression<Func<TResult, T>>>(
        e => Task.FromResult(valueFunc(e)));
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
repo.Setup(x => x.FindAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync<IRepository, int, bool>(e => context.GetSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(e));
```

Essentially, this version of `ReturnsAsync` takes a function that expects a predicate function (which is `e`) and returns a `T`.  This allows you to then execute the predicate against your test data set (`context.GetSet<T>.FirstOrDefault`).  Also, I used the overload of `Returns` that accepts a type parameter; this is used to forward the arguments from the `Setup` call to the function specified as the `Returns` argument.

Your version's signature only specified the predicate, so you had no way to execute it against your test data.  You also had the `T` and `TResult` type parameters backwards in the `valueFunc` parameter's type.